# Thesis formatting according to given conditions

Tags: titlesec, thesis

I want to set these properties in my thesis.

- Chapter heading :All Capital—14 Font size, Bold
- Section heading:Title case-12 Font size, Bold
- Sub-section heading :Sentence case-12
  Font size, Bold Body
- text :Sentence case - 12 Font size

Is this correct?

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}{\normalfont\large\bfseries}{\thechapter}{14pt}{\large}
\titleformat{\section}
{\normalfont\bfseries}{\thesection}{12pt}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}
{\normalfont\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{12pt}{}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}
{\normalfont\bfseries}{\thesubsubsection}{12pt}{}
```

Comment: I think a full example also showing which class you use would be very helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the answer is like [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/234546/chapter-section-subsections-title-font-size/234551#234551)

for text you need

```
 \documentclass[12pt]{report}
```

for other titles

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{blindtext} % just for test text
\usepackage{titlesec}


\newcommand{\chapfnt}{\fontsize{14}{17}}
\newcommand{\secfnt}{\fontsize{12}{14}}
\newcommand{\ssecfnt}{\fontsize{12}{14}}

\titleformat{\chapter}%[display]
{\normalfont\chapfnt\scshape}{\thechapter}{20pt}{\chapfnt}

\titleformat{\section}
{\normalfont\secfnt\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}

\titleformat{\subsection}
{\normalfont\ssecfnt\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}

\titlespacing*{\chapter} {0pt}{50pt}{40pt}
\titlespacing*{\section} {0pt}{3.5ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{2.3ex plus .2ex}
\titlespacing*{\subsection} {0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}

\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\blinddocument

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, but I want chapter heading as "1 INTRODUCTION"?

Comment: @NilaniAlgiriyage ok i will edit my answer

Comment: @NilaniAlgiriyage answer edited

Comment: Thanks again..Just one question..How to bold chapter heading? Using "\bfseries" doesn't work?

Comment: you shoud add \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

Comment: @NilaniAlgiriyage you're welcome